# Aggregate function as condition

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, having

I'm having problem trying to use aggregate function result as a condition. Basically, I need to select rows that have "View count" more than 3. Here is code that works:

```
SELECT b.BranchNo AS "Branch Number",
p.PropertyNo || ', ' || p.PostCode || ', ' || p.City || ', ' || p.Street AS "Object address" , count(v.ViewDate) as "View count"
FROM Branch b INNER JOIN PropertyForRent p ON b.BranchNo=p.PropertyBranchNo 
INNER JOIN Viewing v ON p.PropertyNo=v.ViewPropertyNo WHERE v.ViewDate>='2014-01-01' 
GROUP BY b.BranchNo,  p.PropertyNo;
```

I was trying to use something like that:

```
HAVING count(v.ViewDate)>=3
```

But that obviously didn't work. Is there a way of making such condition without using a subquery?

Comment: `But that obviously didn't work`....uhm, why didn't that work?

Comment: As I know HAVING clause must be getting group made by either GROUP BY or by default using current table. And yeah, that didn't just execute...

Comment: Why wouldn't HAVING work for you?  Where were you trying to put the HAVING clause in your query?

Comment: @Glebzex sorry, didn't understand your comment. Post the whole code that *didn't work* and the error message

Comment: After WHERE clause.

Comment: Try it after the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: SELECT b.BranchNo AS "Branch Number",
p.PropertyNo || ', ' || p.PostCode || ', ' || p.City || ', ' || p.Street AS "Object address" , count(v.ViewDate) as "View count"
FROM Branch b INNER JOIN PropertyForRent p ON b.BranchNo=p.PropertyBranchNo 
INNER JOIN Viewing v ON p.PropertyNo=v.ViewPropertyNo WHERE v.ViewDate>='2014-01-01' HAVING count(v.ViewDate)>=3
GROUP BY b.BranchNo,  p.PropertyNo;

Comment: Group by comes before having change the order of those two... should work. aslo group by can't use the alias, you have to fully qualify objeect_Address

Comment: it needs to be after the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @MatRichardson Oh... That;s just it... Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fields in your `select` don't match up with the `group by`, but other than that, the "condition based on aggregate" is exactly what the `having` clause is for.  For example, this query should work:

```
SELECT 
b.BranchNo AS "Branch Number",
p.PropertyNo || ', ' || p.PostCode || ', ' || p.City || ', ' || p.Street AS "Object address" , 
count(v.ViewDate) as "View count"
FROM Branch b INNER JOIN PropertyForRent p ON b.BranchNo=p.PropertyBranchNo 
INNER JOIN Viewing v ON p.PropertyNo=v.ViewPropertyNo WHERE v.ViewDate>='2014-01-01' 
GROUP BY b.BranchNo, p.PropertyNo, p.PostCode, p.City, p.Street
HAVING count(v.ViewDate) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do grouping in Viewing table sub-query to get the counts. Then join to that.

```
SELECT b.BranchNo AS [Branch Number],
    p.PropertyNo + ', ' + p.PostCode + ', ' + p.City + ', ' + p.Street AS [Object address],
    v.ViewCount

FROM Branch b 
    INNER JOIN PropertyForRent p ON b.BranchNo=p.PropertyBranchNo 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ViewPropertyNo, COUNT(*) as ViewCount 
                FROM Viewing 
                WHERE v.ViewDate>='2014-01-01' 
                GROUP BY ViewPropertyNo
                ) AS v ON p.PropertyNo = v.ViewPropertyNo 
WHERE v.ViewCount >= 3;
```